Is there a way to abstract bridge entities in EF Core?
I am exploring the design space possible with EF Core 8. The problem I am exploring right now is trying to abstract away some of the EF Core entity configuration for a bridge entity that has additional data.
Given the following abstract class:
public abstract class Bridge<Q,R,S,T> where Q : Entity<R> where S : Entity<T>
{
    protected internal Q Left { get; set; }
    protected internal R LeftId { get; set; }
    protected internal S Right { get; set; }
    protected internal T RightId { get; set; }
}

I have the following implemented bridge entity:
public class TestBridgeEntity : Bridge<LeftSideEntity, Guid, RightSideEntity, Guid>
{
    public LeftSideEntity MyLeftSideEntity 
    {
        get { return Left; } 
        set { Left = value; } 
    }
    
    public Guid LeftSideEntityId 
    {
        get { return LeftId; } 
        set { LeftId = value; } 
    }

    public RightSideEntity MyRightSideEntity 
    {
        get { return Right; } 
        set { Right = value; } 
    }

    public Guid RightSideEntityId 
    { 
        get { return RightId; } 
        set { RightId = value; } 
    }

    public double MyTestData { get; set; }
}

I am then hoping to be able to write an extension method to streamline the configuration of the entity which looks like this:
public static EntityTypeBuilder<T> ConfigureBridge<T,A,B,C,D>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder, string leftIdName, string rightIdName)
 where T : Bridge<A,B,C,D> where A: Entity<B> where C:Entity<D>
{
    builder.HasKey(x => new { x.LeftId, x.RightId } );

    builder.HasOne(x => x.Left)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.LeftId);

    builder.HasOne(x => x.Right)
           .WithMany()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.RightId);

    builder.Property(e => e.LeftId).HasColumnName(leftIdName);
    builder.Property(e => e.RightId).HasColumnName(rightIdName);

    return builder;
}

I would then use this extension method inside an IEntityTypeConfiguration class:
internal class MyTestBirdgeEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TestBridgeEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TestBridgeEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("test_bridge");
        builder.ConfigureBridge<TestBridgeEntity, MyLeftSideEntity, Guid, MyRightSideEntity, Guid>("left_side_id", "right_side_id");

        builder.Property(e => e.MyTestData ).IsRequired();
    }
}

My LeftSideEntity has the following relevant definition:
public class LeftSideEntity
{
    // ...

    public List<RightSideEntity> RightSideEntities { get; }
    public List<TestBridgeEntity> TestBridgeEntities { get; }

    // ...
}

And my RightSideEntity has no reference to the LeftSideEntities
When I try and create the database migration I get the following error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'TestDbContext'. The exception ''TestBridgeEntity.LeftId' and 'TestBridgeEntity.LeftSideEntityId' are both mapped to column 'left_side_id' in 'test_bridge', but the properties are contained within the same hierarchy. All properties on an entity type must be mapped to unique different columns.'

Is there a way to get this kind of bridge entity abstraction working?

This seems complete overkill. If you have a simple class PersonThing { [Id] public Person Person {get;set;} [Id] public Thing Thing {get;set;} } then EF will automatically create the columns PersonId and ThingId both of which will be part of the primary key. So most of that config is unnecessary anyway.

I know that its possible to configure an entity directly that way, and if it was for a singular instance of a bridge entity i would understand, but I'm trying to explore the capabilities on if i wanted to have a standardized convention inside my project that would help me enforce certain behaviors via polymorphism

When a joining table consists of just the FK relationships between left and right side, there is no need to even declare a joining entity. The EF configuration just needs to describe the joining table and FKs. A joining entity is only necessary if there are additional properties specific to the join itself. (columns in the joining table) Even with a joining entity you do not double-up relationships as in A.Bs & A.ABs, Without a joining entity it is just A.Bs (and B.As), With a joining entity it is A.ABs and B.ABs.  Keep it simple.

Then you should create your own Convention if there is something that EF Core is not implementing, rather than messing with polymorphism, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/conventions I just don't get why you need to overcomplicate this

How many join entities do you have to make this generalization worth the effort? Also, it seems a terrible nuisance to work with these "Left..."/"Right..." properties in code. Just use join entities with sensible names wherever they're useful.

Bridge and TestBridgeEntity both have properties representing the column value? Only of these properties should exist. Besides .HasMany().WithMany().UsingEntity() isn't that verbose https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-class-for-join-entity
